# Sailjs: how do I save collections with particular fields to the mongo db via waterline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm using no `FeedParser` to loop through a particular XML feed -
I'm getting the required data I want in my console using the following:

```
console.log('Got article: %s', item.title);
console.log('Got url %s', item.link);
```

Here is what I want to do:

- Save the title + links generated as a document in the collection with the same name as the controller name
- I've also setup a cron job so I want to make sure that if the title exists in that collection, the loop should continue to the next article in the RSS feed

Here is what I tried writing below my console.log statements mentioned above and the loop broke after executing once (Buzzfeed is the name of the model so appropriately 'buzzfeed' is the name of the collection where I want the data to be stored)

```
Buzzfeed.findOrCreate()
.populate('title')
.populate('url')
.exec(function (err, title, url){

  buzzfeed[1].title.add(item.title );
  buzzfeed[1].url = ( item.url );
  buzzfeed[1].save(function (err) {
  });

});
```

Addition: Also tried the following and it did not work:

```
db.buzzfeed.save( { title: item.title, url: item.link } );
```

Comment: Your code of using `Waterline ORM` is wrong, try to read a documentation first http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/findOrCreate.html

Comment: Thanks Andi, ya realized that I was doing it wrong, will post answer to my own question next - thanks a tone for replying

Answer (score 0):

As Andi mentioned above, my code was incorrect, the following query solved it for me:

```
Buzzfeed.create({'title': newData.title, 'url': newData.link}, function (err, newTitles) {
});
```